# Add more tabs in Xamarin forms TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a requirement like adding more number of Tabs in TabbedPage .Initially it was 5 in numbers and working fine .While I am adding one more tab (say 6th ) the android version of the App is triggering a 'illegalArgumentException'

The IOS version is not triggering any error instead it loads tab from 5th position to a new listview for which the appearance is not so great.

Appreciating any solution for this .

Comment: What's your XF version? I could not reproduce your issue in my project.

Comment: The  Version is - 3.6

Comment: You could try to update the XF version to the latest.

Answer (score -1):

How about using buttons and icon fonts instead of tabbedPage ?
You can show buttons 6 or more .
[image]

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<!-- Put contents here -->
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End"
                          >
        <Button FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
        Text="&#xF1514;" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Blue"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
        <Button FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
        Text="&#xF1513;" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Blue"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                    <Button FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
        Text="&#xF1512;" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Blue"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                    <Button FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
        Text="&#xF1511;" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Blue"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
        <Button FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"
                Text="&#xF158C;" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Blue"
         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
        <Button FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
        Text="&#xF1543;" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Blue"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for Replying .Seems this will work  but I am seeking any solution on Tabbed page as the implementation is already done  and I don't want to alter the existing flow .